# Launching an iOS app on Vision Pro Simulator Error: Simulator device returned an error for the requested operation

Tags: ios, xcode, visionos

I have a iOS app which I'm trying to test on a Apple Vision Pro Simulator from XCode 15 Beta 2.

The app builds successfully, but I'm getting the following error when the app should launch on the simulator:

```
Simulator device returned an error for the requested operation.
Domain: FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain
Code: 1
Failure Reason: The request was denied by service delegate (SFBSystemService) for reason: NotFound ("Launch Transaction error").
User Info: {
    BSErrorCodeDescription = RequestDenied;
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-06-25 12:10:54 +0000";
    FBSOpenApplicationRequestID = 0x2d7a;
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
    SimCallingSelector = "launchApplicationWithID:options:pid:error:";
}
--
The request to open "myBundleIdentifier" failed.
Domain: FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain
Code: 1
Failure Reason: The request was denied by service delegate (SFBSystemService) for reason: NotFound ("Launch Transaction error").
User Info: {
    BSErrorCodeDescription = RequestDenied;
    FBSOpenApplicationRequestID = 0x2d7a;
}
--
The operation couldn’t be completed. Launch Transaction error
Domain: FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain
Code: 4
Failure Reason: Launch Transaction error
User Info: {
    BSErrorCodeDescription = NotFound;
}
--

Event Metadata: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "RealityDevice14,1";
    "device_osBuild" = "1.0 (21N5165g)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.xrsimulator";
    "dvt_coredevice_version" = "325.3";
    "dvt_mobiledevice_version" = "1643.0.15.100.1";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 68891;
    "operation_errorCode" = 1;
    "operation_errorDomain" = FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain;
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDERunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_consoleMode" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 3;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.xrsimulator";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphonesimulator17.0";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "17.0";
    "sdk_variant" = iphonesimulator;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 13.4 (Build 22F66)
Xcode 15.0 (22181.22) (Build 15A5161b)
Timestamp: 2023-06-25T15:10:54+03:00
```

Cleaning the build folder and restarting XCode & the simulator does not seem to help.

Any suggestions on what else I could try are appreciated.

Comment: Update: I have tried running the app with XCode 15 Beta 3, and the same error occurs.

Comment: Update 2: Same in Beta 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason I was getting this error was because of an Environment Variable.

I had to select my scheme, and select `Edit Scheme`. I have selected the `Arguments` tab, and under `Environment Variables` I had an empty variable:

[image]

As soon as I have unchecked the checkbox next to it, the problem has gone away.

Answer (score 1):

Following solution worked for me:

> To solve the issue select Project -> Build Settings. Search Mach-O Type, change type to Executable.

Refer: [https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/655691?login=true#:~:text=To%20solve%20the%20issue%20select](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/655691?login=true#:%7E:text=To%20solve%20the%20issue%20select)

Comment: In my case, this was already set to Executable

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me in beta 4, and the solution was really simple in my case. You just need to manually open the Vision Pro simulator before running the app. For some reason, if you run the app and the simulator opens from there, it gives you that error.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me, I received the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The "change to type Executable for Mach-O" didnt work for me

I found

"Loading an excessive number of 'test apps' in the beta version of Xcode may at times result in the mentioned error. However, this issue is usually temporary and should rectify itself over time. You need not worry excessively about this problem; instead, continue to experiment and learn.

Even if you try deleting the problematic folder, please note that it will persist in your system's memory and will likely reload when you reopen the Xcode 15 beta. Nonetheless, this behavior is typical of the beta version and does not represent a persistent problem. As you continue to use the software, the loading of your content should gradually improve."

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/732481

Hopefully this helps

Comment: I'm not sure to which "problematic folder" does your answer refer to? I have tried to deploy the app 20+ times, nothing "gradually improved".

Comment: check your xcode 15beta, New version was released aug 8th. >..<

Comment: I've installed the latest xcode, beta 6, and the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I couldn't find out the root of this issue but the only way to make it work again was:

### For faulty Simulator

- From `Window` -> `Device and Simulators (⇧ ⌘ 2)`
- Remove the faulty visionOS simulator
- Add a fresh one
- Run again

[image: Device and Simulators]

✅ No it works as expected

---

#### For faulty Xcode Preview

- Close the Simulator (if its open)
- Open the `Activity Monitor.app`
- Filter vision pro processes
- Select and `Force Quit` all of them
- Rerun the preview

[image: Activity Monitor]

✅ No it works as expected